# How do I create this table in ORACLE SQL without error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to create the following two tables in ORACLE SQL Database however receive ORA-00904. The first table creates fine however the second one refuses to cooperate and failed at the first line. Would be grateful for any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(ORDER_NUMBER VARCHAR(4),
ORDER_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT ORDER_ORDER_DATE_NN NOT NULL,
CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT ORDER_CUSTOMER_NAME_NN NOT NULL,
POSTAGE NUMBER(4,2) CONSTRAINT ORDER_POSTAGE_NN NOT NULL,
ORDER_TOTAL NUMBER(8,2),
 CONSTRAINT ORDER_NUM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUMBER)
 );



CREATE TABLE ITEMS
(ITEM_NUMBER VARCHAR(3),
ITEM_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_NN NOT NULL, 
SIZE VARCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_SIZE_NN NOT NULL, 
COST NUMBER(4,2) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_COST_NN NOT NULL,
QUANTITY NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_QUANTITY_NN NOT NULL, 
ORDER_NUMBER NUMBER(5),
    CONSTRAINT ITEM_ITEM_NUM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_NUMBER),
    CONSTRAINT ITEM_ORDER_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NUMBER)
        REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDER_NUMBER),
);
```

Comment: I suggest you take SQL Server out of the title.

Comment: ORA-0094 is "invalid identifier" which means one of the names (table or column for example) is invalid. Also in Oracle, don't use `VARCHAR`, use `VARCHAR2`

Comment: Perhaps `size` is a reserved word. Try changing it slightly or wrapping it in quotes  `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following :

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
  ORDER_NUMBER NUMBER(5),
  ORDER_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT ORDER_ORDER_DATE_NN NOT NULL,
  CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT ORDER_CUSTOMER_NAME_NN NOT NULL,
  POSTAGE NUMBER(4,2) CONSTRAINT ORDER_POSTAGE_NN NOT NULL,
  ORDER_TOTAL NUMBER(8,2),
  CONSTRAINT ORDER_NUM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NUMBER)
);

CREATE TABLE ITEMS
(
  ITEM_NUMBER VARCHAR2(3),
  ITEM_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_NN NOT NULL, 
  "SIZE" VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_SIZE_NN NOT NULL, 
  COST NUMBER(4,2) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_COST_NN NOT NULL,
  QUANTITY NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT ITEMS_QUANTITY_NN NOT NULL, 
  ORDER_NUMBER NUMBER(5),
  CONSTRAINT ITEM_ITEM_NUM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_NUMBER),
  CONSTRAINT ITEM_ORDER_NUM_FK FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NUMBER)
        REFERENCES ORDERS (ORDER_NUMBER)
);
```

- Referenced columns( `ORDER_NUMBER` ) should be of the same type.
  Whether make both `NUMBER` or `VARCHAR2(4)` type. ( *I suggest storing as NUMBER type if both values for both columns consist of numeric values completely. Since managing a NUMBER value is better than a STRING value.* )
- `SIZE` is a reserved keyword. So convert this name to a proper one
  such as `"SIZE"` or `SIZE_` etc.
- There's an extra comma that needs to be removed just before ending
  `CREATE TABLE ITEMS'`
  bracket
- using `VARCHAR2` for a string type variable instead of `VARCHAR` is suggested by `Oracle`.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your quick help. :)

Comment: *VARCHAR2 type considers an empty string and NULL are both equal, while VARCHAR doesn't.* - not yet. It's still "scheduled" and recommended not to be used [as of 18c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Hi, it seems the document suggests varchar2 due to `different comparison semantics`. What's wrong with "empty string and NULL comparison"?

Comment: It is incorrect to say there is a difference between `varchar2` and `varchar`, as they are currently synonymous (as of 18c). The documentation has been saying more or less the same thing about `varchar` since the early 1990's, including the instruction not to use it.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson ok, I tested that not an exact problem appears with null and empty strings, thanks for this, but the reason of using varchar2 rather than varchar is not clear enough. There seems no rigid reason, only behind the scenes.

Comment: `VARCHAR` is a standartised type, `VARCHAR2` is Oracle extension. They are both identical, but the extension is prepared if the standard would cause problems, the extension would safe the world;)

Answer (score 0):

My version would be:

```
create table orders
( order_number       varchar2(4) constraint order_num_pk primary key
, order_date         date not null
, customer_name      varchar2(50) not null
, postage            number(4,2) not null
, order_total        number(8,2)
);

create table items
( item_number        varchar2(3) constraint item_item_num_pk primary key
, item_description   varchar2(500) not null
, order_number       constraint item_order_num_fk references orders (order_number)
, item_size          varchar2(1) not null
, cost               number(4,2) not null
, quantity           number(4) not null
);
```

- While it's useful to give explicit names to primary, unique and (maybe) foreign keys, naming NOT NULL constraints is generally considered overkill.
- Defining single-column constraints inline with the column definition is less verbose and also lets FK columns inherit the datatype of the referenced column, which I personally consider best practice.
- Defining columns with "number" in the name that are not actually numbers seems to be asking for trouble, but it's your data model.
- "ITEMS" might be ambiguous if you have inventory items as well as order items, but again it's up to you.
- `SIZE` is part of `CREATE CLUSTER` syntax and therefore not allowed as a column name. You could name it `"SIZE"` (double-quotes) but you will have to refer to it that way every time, forever, so I used `item_size` instead.
- I code in lowercase, because it's not COBOL and this isn't 1974.